# How to add html tags to account setting emails?

Tags: emails, users

I am working on a project where I need to add some custom headers to the email which we send to the user on registration. Is there a module which support this functionality?

Comment: The HTML Mail module (http://drupal.org/project/htmlmail) looks like a good place to start.

Comment: so @Syed Hashim : could you comment us if Mail Headers module linked in my answer below fits your needs ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Mail Headers](http://drupal.org/project/mail_headers) project. 
As says doc, it allows you to control and modify any (almost any) mail header.

Comment: I used swift mailer. It supports the HTML tags in email templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom header to the email by using a custom module that uses [hook_mail_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/8.2.x) to set the custom email headers.

You can also use these contrib modules:

- [X-Originating-IP email header](https://www.drupal.org/project/x_originating_ip)
- [Mail Headers](https://www.drupal.org/project/mail_headers)